# Multiprocessing with Python Process

Tags: python, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to modify a Python script to multiprocess with "Process". The problem is it's not working. In a first step, the content is retrieved sequentially (test1, test2). In a second one, it is to be called in parallel (test1 and test2). There is practically no speed difference.  If you execute the functions individually, you will notice a difference. In my opinion, parallelization should only take as long as the longest individual process. What am I missing here?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def test1(k):
           k = k * k
           for e in  range(1, k):
                          e = e**k
def test2(k):
           k = k * k
           for e in  range(1, k):
                          e = e + 5 - 5*k ** 4000
if __name__ == '__main__':

           start = time.time()
           test1(100)
           test2(100)
           end = time.time()
           print(end-start)

           start = time.time()
           worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1(100))
           worker_1.start()

           worker_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(100,))
           worker_2.start()

           worker_1.join()
           worker_2.join()
           end = time.time()
           print(end-start)
```

I want to add that I checked the task manager and saw that only 1 core is used. (4 real Core only 25% CPU => 1Core 100% used)

I know Pool Class, but I don't want to use it.

Thank you for your help.

## Update

Hello, everybody,
the one with the "typo" was unfavorable. Sorry about that. Bakuriu, thank you for your answer. In fact, you're right.  I think it was the typo and too much work.  :-( So I changed the example once again.  For all who are interested:

I create two functions, in the first part of the main I run 3 times the functions sequentially. My computer needs approx. 36 sec. Then I start two new processes. These calculate their results here in parallel. As a small addition, the skin process of the program itself also calculates the function test1, which should show that the main program itself can also do something. I get a computing time of 12 sec. So that it is comprehensible for all in the Internet, what this means I once attached a picture here.
[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4T9.png)

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def test1(k):
           k = k * k
           for e in  range(1, k):
                          e = e**k

def test2(k):
           k = k * k
           for e in  range(1, k):
                          e = e**k

if __name__ == '__main__':


           start = time.time()
           test1(100)
           test2(100)
           test1(100)
           end = time.time()
           print(end-start)


           start = time.time()
           worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(100,))
           worker_1.start()

           worker_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2, args=(100,))
           worker_2.start()

           test1(100)

           worker_1.join()
           worker_2.join()
           end = time.time()
           print(end-start)
```

Comment: "I know Pool Class, but I don't want to use it." Why? I think you're launching the processes serially and only launching a single process each time, so there's no reason for it to be faster.

Comment: @roganjosh From my point of view, multiprocessing is the parallisation package of Python with the classes Pool and Process. Both enable parallel processing. Or is that wrong? This is a mini example. My actual code is extremely long, but it reflects the problem.

Comment: Yes it is, but each process is still bound by the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). If you're only launching a single process at a time to try do heavy CPU work, you might as well have just stuck with the original process you were running and not used `multiprocessing`. It only works if you can divide work up amongst multiple concurrent processes. A `multiprocessing.Process` does not do anything faster than the original process you're already running on its own.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the answer. Now I'm not sure if I understood that correctly, I thought with "Process" I'd start my own process running on another core? If not, how do I get there?

Comment: That's true, but you're not instructing your current process to do anything. So you just offload the work on to another process that runs exactly like the one you're already running (if it's CPU-bound). You said you don't want to use a Pool and I asked why; you haven't answered that.

Comment: Hello, I had understood pool variant in such a way that one and the same function/method can be executed with different arguments in parallel. However, since I want to execute several different functions, each with specific parameters, this is not so easy,......but I would like to be informed better. Please see my next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing sequentially because instead of passing `test1` to the `Process`'s `target` argument you are passing `test1`'s *result* to it!

You want to do this:

```
worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, args=(100,))
```

As you do in the other call **not** this:

```
worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1(100))
```

This code is *first* executing  `test1(100)`, then returns `None` and assigns that to `target` spawning an "empty process". After that you spawn a second process that executes `test2(100)`. So you execute the code sequentially plus you add the overhead of spawning two processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that at least explains an error in the code. Now the real problem is still there, though, and I only use one core and not two as I had thought.

Comment: @Airfox It seems like `test1` is taking almost all of the time. I tried to run your program printing the time for the first and second task sequential and then the time for the parallel version. The numbers are: first task: `8.730686902999878`, second task `2.1878798008`, both tasks in parallel `8.73914003372`. As you can see the parallel version **is** running in the same time as the task that ends last. Unfortunately that task lasts *way* longer than the other once hence it does not parallelize well